# Footcite number should count up

Tags: numbering, footnotes

I'm currently working on a report... It says that every footnote should have a unique number, aka it should count up. But when I use  `\footcite{Mandelbrot1987}` it will only count the numbers up per page. When I have two footcites on one page, it will be 1 and 2. But every new page it begins at 1 again, is there any way to change that? It should count globally, not per page.
Litte Code:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[
  paper=a4paper,
  left=30mm,
  right=40mm,
  top=30mm,
  bottom=25mm,
  includefoot,
  foot=\baselineskip,
  bindingoffset=0mm]{geometry}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authortitle]{biblatex}
\usepackage[babel,german=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage{url}
\setmainfont{Calibri}
\linespread {1.5}
\title{Something}
\author{Someone}
\date{2013}
\addbibresource{literatur.bib}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg,.eps}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\chapter{Einleitung}
\footcite{Barnsley1995}
\newpage
\chapter{Somethingelse}
\footcite{Barnsley1995}
\newpage
\chapter{More}
\footcite{Barnsley1995}
\newpage
\end{document}
```

And the Bib:

```
@BOOK{Barnsley1995,
    AUTHOR = {Barnsley, Michael F. AND Meyer, Jens},
    YEAR = {1995},
    TITLE = {Fraktale. - Theorien und Praxis der deterministischen Geometrie.},
    EDITION = {1. Aufl.},
    ISBN = {978-3-860-25010-5},
    PUBLISHER = {Spektrum-Akademischer Vlg},
    LOCATION = {München},
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I added an example code. I think it has to do with chapters. When you compile that with xelatex and look at the PDF, ever footnote will be number 1

Comment: Hi! I hope I didn't mess it now, we seem to have performed an edit at quite the same time. Shall you please provide `literatur.bib`, then it'll be just perfect :)

Comment: There you go, just paste that into literatur.bib

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your footnote citations aren't numbered per page, but per chapter. (In your example, you'd notice the difference if you didn't start a new chapter after each manual page break.) This is by design of classes like `scrreprt` that feature the `\chapter` command.

For continuous numbering of footnotes, add the following to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter}
```

Also note that new chapters automatically start a new page, so issuing `\newpage` isn't required.